# How to use PHP preg_match for text between a colon and period?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this string:

```
$style = "width:87.0%;";
```

How do I use PHP preg_match() to extract just "87" from it?  For the life of me I can't get my head wrapper around regex :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/:(.*?)\./', $style, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

The `?` makes the regex reluctant/ungreedy

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('~:(\d+)\.~', 'width:87.0%;', $m);
print_r($m);
print $m[1]; // 87
```

`\d` only digits, `+` one or more times, `()` group (catch) it to use later.